# Powershell - Output directory recurse to console and file

Tags: powershell

I'm outputting share folder structures to a text file using the code below:

```
$path = "\\server\share"
$file = "c:\share-folders.txt"
get-childitem "$path" -recurse -directory | select -expand fullname >> "$file"
```

I would also like to write it to the console at the same time as a way of tracking status.  I've tried using tee-object to append the file and then pipe to write-host, but at best I have only been able to output to the text file, or to the console, but not both at once.  Does anyone know the proper method to accomplish this?

---

**Solution:** Adding -Append to the end of the Tee-Object cmdlet resolved the issue.

```
$path = "\\server\share"
$file = "c:\share-folders.txt"
Get-ChildItem "$Path" -Recurse -Directory | Select -Expand FullName | Tee-Object -FilePath "$File" -Append
```

Comment: See Tee-Object in your documentation.

Comment: Did you try all examples in http://ss64.com/ps/tee-object.html yet?

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses, and apologize for the delayed reply - project got put on hold for a few weeks to deal with a couple others that caught fire.  I had tried Tee-Object unsuccessfully, but I'll try it again with the suggestions below and the ss64.com documentation and post an update shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
get-childitem "$path" -recurse -directory |  select -expand fullname | %{ Write-Output $_ ; $_ >> "$file"}
```

Following this, with the Tee commandlet:

```
get-childitem "$path" -recurse -directory |   select -expand fullname | tee -file  "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one:
First select the data and then foreach object add it to text file and write it to the console.

```
$path = "\\server\share"
$file = "c:\share-folders.txt"

Get-ChildItem "$path" -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach-Object {Add-Content -Value $_ -Path $file; Write-Host -Object $_}
```